# If $A$ is hermitian matrix s.t. $A^{99}=I_n$, show that $A=I_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a hermitian matrix that satisfies the property $A^{99}=I_n$. I want to show that $A=I_n$.

By definition, $A$ is a hermitian matrix if $a_{ij}=\overline{a_{ji}}$.

From the fact that $A^{99}=I_n$, we deduce that $A$ is invertible and its inverse is $A^{98}$. Does that help to get that $A=I_n$ ? Or do we use somehow the definition of a hermitian matrix?

Comment: **Hint:** Since $A$ is hermitian, it can be diagonalized. It is easy to write down the entries of a power of a diagonal matrix. And remember that the eigenvalues of $A$ are real.

Comment: So since $A$ is hermitian, there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix.  How does this help? @HenningMakholm

Comment: x @Evinda: Simplify $A^{99} = (PDP^{-1})^{99}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm So, since $A$ is hermitian, there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=PDP^{-1}$. Then $A^{99}=(PDP^{-1})^{99}=(PDP^{-1})(PDP^{-1}) \cdots (PDP^{-1})(PDP^{-1})=PD^{99}P^{-1}$. Right? If so, how do we continue?

Comment: @Evinda What is $D^{99}$?

Comment: It's also a diagonal matrix where at the diagonal we have the elements of the diagonal of $D$ powered by $99$. Right? @TrevorGunn

Comment: @Evinda Right. Now figure out what $A^{99} = I_n$ says about $D^{99}$ and then use the fact that the entries of $D$ are the eigenvalues (real numbers) of $A$ to conclude.

Comment: @TrevorGunn We have that $PD^{99}P^{-1}=I_n \Rightarrow D^{99}=P^{-1}P=I_n$. So $det(D)^{99}=1 \Rightarrow det(D)=\pm 1$. So the product of the eigenvalues is $\pm 1$. Is it right so far?

Comment: @Evinda: You can say more than the determinant.

Comment: @HenningMakholm $D^{99}=I_n$ implies that $D$ is invertible and its inverse is $D^{98}$. Does this help?

Comment: @Evinda: $D$ is a _diagonal_ matrix. As I started by saying, it is easy to write down powers of a diagonal matrix in terms of the diagonal elements.

Comment: $D$ contains the eigenvalues, right? So from $D^{99}=I_n$, do we get that $\lambda^{99}=1$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda$? Thus there is only one eigenvalue, $\lambda=1$. Thus $D=I$ and so $A=PP^{-1}=I_n$. Am I right? @HenningMakholm

Comment: @Evinda: Yes. ${}$

Comment: @HenningMakholm Nice, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @HenningMakholm I like your approach and the way you opened the secrets step by step. Thanks I learned a lot from this approach. Every big problem is just a  combination of small exercises/facts threaded together in a certain way.

Comment: @Evinda Yes, but you must be sure first that the eigenvalues of $A$ are real; otherwise $\lambda^{99}=1$ woul not imply $\lambda=1$. This happens because $A$ is hermitian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ is hermitian so $\sigma(A) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. On the other hand, the polynomial $z^{99} - 1$ annihilates $A$ so

$$\sigma(A) \subseteq \{\text{zeroes of }z^{99}-1\} \cap \mathbb{R} = \left\{e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{99}} : k \in \{0, \ldots, 98\}\right\} \cap \mathbb{R} = \{1\}$$

so $\sigma(A) = \{1\}$.

Since $A$ is diagonalizable, it diagonalizes to the indentity matrix so $A = I$.

Comment: Which is the $\sigma$-function?

Comment: @Evinda $\sigma(A)$ is the [spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_matrix) of $A$, i.e. the set of all eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: And why does it hold that $\sigma(A) \subseteq \{ \text{zeroes of } z^{99}-1\} \cap \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @Evinda $A$ is hermitian so $\sigma(A) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. The polynomial $z^{99} - 1$ annihilates $A$ so the minimal polynomial $m_A$ of $A$ divides $z^{99} - 1$. Therefore
$$\sigma(A) = \{\text{zeroes of }m_A\} \subseteq \{\text{zeroes of } z^{99}-1\}$$
Hence, $\sigma(A)$ is contained in the intersection.

Comment: Ok, so that's how we get that $\sigma(A) \subseteq \{ 1 \}$. And since $\sigma(A)$ is non-empty, it follows that $\sigma(A)=\{1\}$, right? How do we get from the fact that $A$ is diagonizable, that $A=I$ ? @mechanodroid

Comment: @Evinda Yes, precisely. Since $A$ is diagonalizable, there exists an invertible matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A = PDP^{-1}$. The diagonal matrix $D$ has eigenvalues of $A$ along the diagonal, which must all be $1$. Therefore $D = I$ so $A = PIP^{-1} = PP^{-1} = I$.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks a lot :)